# Trouble in IE8 with background gradiation on menu hover elements, working in all other browsers

Tags: internet-explorer, css

Here's the website: http://www.mccaonline.com

I have been hired to work on an issue with the gradiated menu on the site. The menu functions properly in Firefox, Chrome, and Safari - when you hover over a menu element, the background changes to a light gradiated green. In IE8 and IE9, however, all submenu elements are assigned the light green gradiated background.

[Here's how it looks in IE8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Mqmy.jpg)

I just want it to function the same in Internet explorer and can't figure out what's causing it to have the gradiated background on all child menu elements. The CSS I am using for the navigation is as follows:

```
#navigation {
    background: rgb(100,135,125); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%, rgba(126,181,165,1) 50%,   rgba(126,181,165,1) 52%, rgba(143,190,174,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(100,135,125,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(126,181,165,1)), color-stop(52%,rgba(126,181,165,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(143,190,174,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 50%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 52%,rgba(143,190,174,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 50%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 52%,rgba(143,190,174,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 50%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 52%,rgba(143,190,174,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 50%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 52%,rgba(143,190,174,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#64877d', endColorstr='#8fbeae',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
}
/*  HOVER STATE OF NAV BAR  */
#navigation ul.nav > li:hover,
#navigation ul.nav > li a:hover,
ul.nav li.current_page_item a,
ul.nav li.current_page_parent a,
ul.nav li.current-menu-ancestor a,
ul.nav li.current-cat a,
ul.nav   li.li.current-menu-item a {
    background: rgb(100,135,125); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%, rgba(136,197,158,1) 47%, rgba(196,233,188,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(100,135,125,1)), color-stop(47%,rgba(136,197,158,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(196,233,188,1))); /*   Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(136,197,158,1) 47%,rgba(196,233,188,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(136,197,158,1) 47%,rgba(196,233,188,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(136,197,158,1) 47%,rgba(196,233,188,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(136,197,158,1) 47%,rgba(196,233,188,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#64877d', endColorstr='#c4e9bc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */
    color: #ffffff;
} 
 #navigation { 
    background: rgb(100,135,125); /* Old browsers */ 
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */ 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%, rgba(126,181,165,1) 50%,   rgba(126,181,165,1) 52%, rgba(143,190,174,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */ 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(100,135,125,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(126,181,165,1)), color-stop(52%,rgba(126,181,165,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(143,190,174,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */ 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 50%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 52%,rgba(143,190,174,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */ 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 50%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 52%,rgba(143,190,174,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */ 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 50%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 52%,rgba(143,190,174,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */ 
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 50%,rgba(126,181,165,1) 52%,rgba(143,190,174,1) 100%); /* W3C */ 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#64877d', endColorstr='#8fbeae',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */ 
} 
/*  HOVER STATE OF NAV BAR  */ 
#navigation ul.nav > li:hover, 
#navigation ul.nav > li a:hover, 
ul.nav li.current_page_item a, 
ul.nav li.current_page_parent a, 
ul.nav li.current-menu-ancestor a, 
ul.nav li.current-cat a, 
ul.nav   li.li.current-menu-item a { 
    background: rgb(100,135,125); /* Old browsers */ 
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */ 
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%, rgba(136,197,158,1) 47%, rgba(196,233,188,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */ 
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(100,135,125,1)), color-stop(47%,rgba(136,197,158,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(196,233,188,1))); /*   Chrome,Safari4+ */ 
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(136,197,158,1) 47%,rgba(196,233,188,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */ 
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(136,197,158,1) 47%,rgba(196,233,188,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */ 
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(136,197,158,1) 47%,rgba(196,233,188,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */ 
    background: linear-gradient(top,  rgba(100,135,125,1) 0%,rgba(136,197,158,1) 47%,rgba(196,233,188,1) 100%); /* W3C */ 
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#64877d', endColorstr='#c4e9bc',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */ 
    color: #ffffff; 
}
```

Let me know what you think or what could be causing this. I greatly appreciate any help!

Comment: @RobertHarvey - only 4 eligible questions

Answer (score 1):

Add this in your css.

```
#navigation ul.nav .sub-menu li:hover , #navigation ul.nav .sub-menu li a:hover {background:none!important
```

you will get your solution.

Comment: do the background-image as none as well

Comment: So I added the following:   #navigation ul.nav .sub-menu li:hover , #navigation ul.nav .sub-menu li a:hover {background:none!important; background-image:none !important}    I am still getting the same error.  Thank you for giving this a shot though.

Answer (score 0):

Your styles don't use the .sub-menu class, did you try remove the background with a class like:

```
.sub-menu .menu-item {
  background: ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Take off your filter tag and handle the menu in jquery. it affects ie 2 levels down on menus.